# Why client-side load balancers like Ribbon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, netflix

Netflix makes use of Ribbon, which is in their terms a "client-side load-balancer". What are the use-cases and advantages of a client-side load-balancer compared to a traditional load-balancer? Is Ribbon, and other Netflix OSS services AWS -specific or can they be used in other contexts?

Comment: When Should a client use a load balancer?
Here I am referring to Client as a Micro Service it self.
Does it add any overhead on the microservice/client.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already mentioned by using Ribbon you don't need an additional load balancer. You can also configure the balancing algorithm for each client differently, if you need to. At first I was a bit surprised also, but it does make a lot of sense.

Currently Spring Cloud, which uses Netflix OSS for most part, is independent of AWS.

I have made a small POC that you can check out [here](https://github.com/Oreste-Luci/netflix-oss-example) if want.

Answer (score 4):

One reason for using client-side load balancer can be performance. With client side balancer you can directly contact desired service with one network hop (after initial discovery of course); with traditional load-balancer you need two hops - see my very [unprofessional test](http://blog.instea.sk/2015/04/netflix-zuul-vs-nginx-performance/).

Unfortunately I don't have that much experience with Netflix OOS, I just deduce from documentation that at least [Spring Cloud Netflix](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html) can run also e.g. on Cloud Foundry.

Comment: I concur. That additional hop injects latency into every over-the-wire invocation. That caused us trouble. You can easily saturate an ha-proxy server and thus require multiple proxies. Soon it becomes a dev-ops hassle. Other load balances such as the ELB are ideally meant as edge-proxies rather than middle-tier proxies.